# in the Overpass API is there a way to use logical operators on tag existence?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

The Overpass API language guide does allow for logical operators when matching a tag value... for example:`["name"~"holtorf|Gielgen"]` will return whatever object has either name=holtorf or name=Gielgen.

You can also combine conditions and they will become an AND... so for example:

`["name"]["name"="holtorf"]`. Means to search for things that have the tag "name" and that the tag name is equal to "holtorf".

But what I want is an OR operator... something like:

`["name"="holtorf"]|["name:eng"holtorf"]`

In my specific application, I just want to know if there is ANY tag that start with "name"... so what I would like to do is put this into the API: `["^name"]` (cause in this API "^" means "starts with"). But of course it searches for literal "^name" and returns nothing.

Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no OR operation, but you can use UNION

```
(
  way["name"="holtorf"];
  way["name:eng"=holtorf"]
);
```

There is also a DIFFERENCE and negotiation http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Difference

And in your particular case, you could use key-value regexpressions matching. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Key.2Fvalue_matches_regular_expression_.28.7E.22key_regex.22.7E.22value_regex.22.29

```
[~"^name.*$"~"^holtorf$"];

//or only for key
[~"^name.*$"="Holtorf"];
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm misunderstanding... but are you saying that the correct way to do `["^name"]` is `[~"^name.*$"]`? I'm getting "Error: line 10: parse error: A regular expression for a key can only be combined with a regular expression as value criterion". I don't care about "holtorf", I just want to find any objects that have a tag "name" or "name:en" or "name:fr" etc. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check `[~"^name.*$"="Holtorf"]` variant. Just use `[~"^name.*$"~"^holtorf$"]` If you want all objects with name:* and don't care about value, you still have to use regexpression for key and for value (sorry I've mislead you with expressions for key only). For instance `[~"^name:.*$"~"^.*$"]` Note: I'm not sure about should I escape `:` in regexp or not.

Comment: And if you have finite set of keys - use union: `(way[name]; way["name:en"]; way["name:fr"]; way["name:and_so_on"];);`

Comment: Yup! You nailed it. I could simplify what you put in your comment just a bit... what I ended up using was: `[~"^nam[e|e:en|e:fr|e:es]"~"."]`  which captures the existance of `name, name:en, name:fr, name:es`. Thanks!

Comment: How does it comply with the documentaition: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Wizard#Boolean_Operators (example does not work)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
node["place"~"village|city|town|metropolis"]["name"~"^A"](area:3602145268);
```